# How to make rollback commit on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I commited new version my app on heroku. But it was a bad release. 
I got an error `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.`
I tried `heroku rollback`, but the error does not disappear.
I want to roll back to the previous commit on Heroku, but not touch the commit on the git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback): 
The `heroku rollback` command does not roll back the state of any of the following:

- Add-on provisioning (provisioned add-ons remain provisioned, and deprovisioned add-ons remain deprovisioned). Any add-on-related config vars do roll back.
- Your app’s Heroku-hosted Git repository
- Any state stored in add-ons or externally

It is your responsibility to reconcile these resources after rolling back. Consequently, you should use the heroku rollback command only when absolutely necessary.

**Running on a rolled-back release should serve as a temporary fix to a bad deployment**. If you are running on a rolled-back release, **commit a fix to your encountered issue and push it to Heroku**. As always, this updates the heroku Git remote and creates a new release.

So I do not think you can leave the git repo untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku always uses the github branch that you've pushed to it.

The easiest way is to fix it would be to push your github branch to it, without the errors (previous commit).

If you have pushed it to your master branch, you can watch the history of the flawed files and just copy all code that worked in your local branch, push it again to your master (or better, create a branch for it) and push this one again to heroku.